# Flutter ListView.builder not working in alert dialog

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-alertdialog

> I want to display item list in alert dialog, for payment confirmation.
> but it's not working, i tried many solutions.
>
> ```
> AlertDialog(
>       titlePadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
>       contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 0),
>       title: Text("Heading"),
>       content: ListView.builder(
>           shrinkWrap: true,
>           itemCount: items.length,
>           itemBuilder: (ctx, i) {
>             return getRowWidget(i);
>           }),
>     );
> ```

Comment: Please tell us what "it's not working" means. Do you get compiler errors? Runtime errors? Does it no look like you want it to look?

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem, Add `Container` with width.

```
     showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                  titlePadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 0),
                  title: Text("Heading"),
                  content: Container(
                    width: double.maxFinite,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: items.length,
                        itemBuilder: (ctx, i) {
                          return Text(items[i].toString());
                        }),
                  ),
                ),
              );
```

Comment: @Rohit Soni: is this satisfying your requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.

```
       showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                titlePadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                contentPadding:
                    EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 0),
                title: Text("Heading"),
                content: Container(
                  height: 100,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: 1,
                      itemBuilder: (ctx, i) {
                        return Text("text");
                      }),
                ),
              ),
            );
```